# console.log says object is undefined when I call any of its members

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The Environment**

Mozilla Firefox 11 Running MAMP and testing on localhost

**The Error**

dirObject[data] is undefined
http://localhost:8888/framework/
Line 34

**The Symptom**

console.log(**object**[*member*]); produces expected results (returns the **object**), but  console.log(**object**[*member*][*member*]); returns that **object** is undefined.

**dirObject**

```
var dirObject ={
    'directoryName' : {
            directory : 'path/to/the/directory',
            txt       : 'textFileInDirectory.js',
            css       : 'styleSheetFileInDirectory.css',
            js        : 'javaScriptFileInDirectory.js'
    }... // There are currently 27 of these structures in my object.
}
```

**My Code**

```
for(var count = 0; count <= size; count++){
    var data = keys[count];
    console.log(dirObject[data]['directory']);
}
```

-- Returns 'dirObject is undefined' and references the console.logs line number.

```
for(var count = 0; count <= size; count++){
    var data = keys[count];
    console.log(dirObject[data]);
}
```

-- Returns the multi-dimensional object (Contains root link paths and file names for items listed in my plugins directory.  The object exists).

Comment: I don't suppose you'd mind actually including enough for us to duplicate your problem? Browser? Short sample?

Comment: Yes we need to see the structure of `dirObject` and `keys`

Comment: Is that the error message verbatim (if so on which browser)? If not, please copy and paste the error message exactly -- in addition to showing the data structure as requested above

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dPkGs/ -- Simple mockup...if you were in fact paraphrasing the error message it sounds like `'directory'` is just not in your object (maybe typo or extra space or wrong case).

Comment: Sorry about that guys.  First time Posting.   I've edited the initial, in hopes of giving more information, but unfortunately It's a project that contains classified information, so I can't provide much more than what I have up there.   Again thanks for giving me the help you have, and will. :)  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Like @prodigitalson said, the only thing I can see happening is either `dirObject` or `keys` are malformed.

Answer (score 1):

improve a foreach to test your code

```
for (var i in dirObject){ console.log(i); console.log(dirObject[i]); }
```

Comment: dirObject - is an object with a collection of objects representing sub-directories as it's members.  Each of dirObjects member objects (Directories) has 4 variables as their members one is directory which holds the logical path to the directory itself, and the other 3 hold the names of files of their type in them (So css would have the name of the css file within that directory)

Comment: The `directory` can be accessed by using `dirObject[data].directory` as much as `dirObject[data]['directory']`.

Comment: So please call me a moron...  I just figured out the issue.  By console logging the data variable (Which is cycling through a directory, and giving me the directory names of all subd-irectories) the first two items in it are '.' and '..'...  of course there is no dirObject['..'] which is why it comes back undefined, and breaks my code.    Thank you all so much for helping me out with this.   I feel like such a twink.

Comment: improve a foreach to test your code for (var i in dirObject){ console.log(i); console.log(dirObject[i]); }